# Mac Mini won't boot with LG 34 UW monitor Connected

Tags: startup, mac-mini, displayport

Kind of an edge case, so not sure if anyone can help with this. I purchased a new LG 34WP88C for my aging Mac Mini 2012 (6,2) hoping it could drive the display and it does, brilliantly, at 3440 x 1440 but only at 50hz. I'm totally happy with this setup BUT... I just discovered that my Mac Mini now cannot boot with the monitor connected. If I power down the display and restart my Mac. It boots up normally. I just need to turn on the display after it restarts. If I reboot with the display powered on then it says No Signal and the Mac refuses to boot up. I can't wake it up or toggle the display on and off. I have to do a forced shutdown with the power button on the mini. Monitor is connected with Mini DP to DP. HDMI works but won't allow me to achieve the same resolution.

Ok looks like this only happens during a reboot. Shutting down completely allowed it to start to normally with the monitor powered on.

Please any insight or workarounds or fixes for this issue.

Macos Catalina 10.15.7
2.6 GHz Quad Core
16GB RAM

Comment: Are you sure the Mac hasn’t booted?  Get the IP and try to ping or remote connect to it from another machine when it’s exhibiting the symptoms described

Comment: The Mini spec says "Support for up to two displays at 2560 by 1600 pixels, both at millions of colors". No mention of 3440, so I am somewhat surprised it works at any time.

Comment: @Allan yes sure. I have Anydesk loaded but i can't remote in. As soon as I power off the display and boot I can remote in.

Comment: @Gilby yes I'm kinda pushing the limits. The DP port has enough juice for 1440 but only 50hz. Won't work with HDMI. I'm gonna try another cable. Apparently I need an ACTIVE miniDP to HDMI converter cable. I'll report back once I have it installed.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED] The new cable worked! If anybody runs into this issue I'm using an **Active** Mini Displayport to HDMI Cable on a Mac Mini 2012. I'm getting 3440 x 1440 at 50hz and I can totally reboot without any issues during the boot sequence. Do not use HDMI->HDMI or mDP->DP.

[Cable looks like this](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01FM50QJC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

[image]